# How can i add a return statement to magicTime?

Tags: c++, nullpointerexception, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm trying to find the output of the following code.
How can i add a return statement to magicTime? 
The out put should be 
a:  10 b:  30 c:   
a:  10 b:  30

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int magicTime(int a, int &b, const int &c){
    a=c;
    b=20;
}



int main(){

    int a = 10;
    int b = 30;
    int c;

    cout << "a: " << a << " b   " << b << " c   " << c << endl;

    c=b;
    magicTime(c, b, a);

    cout << "a: " << a << " b   " << b << " c   " << c << endl;


    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: By writing `return <something>;` at the end of the function. What should it return?

Comment: I want it to return the values stored at a,b and c.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK so you want to return an array of int

Pseudo code

```
int[] magicTime(int a, int &b, const int &c){
    a=c;
    b=20;
    return new int [] { a, b, c};
}
```

Comment: I seriously doubt that's what the OP wants to do.

Comment: He says he wants to return all three right? Maybe I misunderstood the question